# How do I access a local variable in Active Record query with SQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying some code to find an attribute with a time value that is less than current time.

If I have `current_time = Time.now`, how do I find it using `where` such as:

```
Outage.where("end_time < current_time") # this doesn't work.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do that via placeholder.

### Using ? Placeholder

You can use `?` as a placeholder in a query condition.

```
    User.where('users.name = ?', 'John')
```

With multiple placeholders:

```
    User.where('users.name = ? AND users.last_name = ?', 'John', 'Smith')
```

### Using Named Placeholder

```
    User.where('first_name = :first_name', { :first_name => 'John' })
```

With multiple placeholder:

```
    values = { :first_name => 'John', :last_name => 'Smith'}
    conditions = 'first_name = :first_name AND last_name = :last_name'
    User.where(conditions , values)
```

Noted that order does not matters. The following code would work correctly since we have already **named** those placeholders.

```
    values = { :last_name => 'Smith', :first_name => 'John'}
    conditions = 'first_name = :first_name AND last_name = :last_name'
    User.where(conditions , values)
```

References: [Using Named Placeholders in Ruby](http://www.robbyonrails.com/articles/2005/10/21/using-named-placeholders-in-ruby)

Answer (score 1):

You can use placeholder - `?` and then pass the value, like this:

```
Outage.where('outages.end_time < ?', current_time)
```